# Java recursive routine doubt

Tags: java, recursion

Im implementing a recursive routine to calculate all the terms of a multinomial expression, basically a multinomial expansion. I kind of figured that this translates into a a problem along the following lines --

Given a set of n numbers with values ranging from [0,1,2,...n] what are the maximum number of combinations by which a sum of k can be achieved.

The following is the recursive routine --

```
public static String []multinomial_elements;
public static void multichoose(int n,int k)
{
    String[] result = null;
    System.out.print("Calling multichoose with");
    System.out.println("  "+Integer.toString(n)+"  "+Integer.toString(k));
    if(n==1)
    {
        multinomial_elements[result_iter]=multinomial_elements[result_iter]+Integer.toString(k)+"|";
        ++result_iter;
    }
    else
    {
        if(k==0)
        {
            result=new String[1];
            result[0]="0";
            for(int a=0;a<n;a++)
                multinomial_elements[result_iter]=multinomial_elements[result_iter]+"0"+"|";
            ++result_iter;   
        }
        else 
        {
            for(int firstindexval=k;firstindexval>=0;firstindexval--)
                for(int iter=0;iter<=k-firstindexval;iter++)
                {
                    if(iter+firstindexval==k){

                        multinomial_elements[result_iter]=multinomial_elements[result_iter]+Integer.toString(firstindexval)+"|";

                        multichoose(n-1,iter);
                    }

                }

        }
    }

}
```

multinomial_elements if the array that would contain 1 entry fro every term of the expansion. The basic idea behind the above code is that from the maximum possible value(power) of the first term, I iterate to its lowest possible value(power) and by doing so apply the same logic on other terms recursively. 
From the print statements denoting the function call, Im able to infer that I am able to see that Im traversing the tree in the right manner. The output however seems erratic. I seem to be messing up in the place where im adding 'firstindexval' to the array multinomial_terms. This seems to happen in cases wherein Im returning to a higher node after processing a lower node and hence the program no longer has sense of 'firstindexval'. This inference is based on the output as below --

```
multichoose(3, 3);

3|0|0|
2|1|0|
0|1|
1|2|0|
1|1|
0|2|
0|3|0|
2|1|
1|2|
0|3|
```

Any pointers or hints on what I am doing wrong would be of great help.

Thanks
p1ng

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to be doing what your description suggests it is supposed to. Can you provide a simple example of what you expect the output to be and why? What should `multichoose(3, 3);` calculate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The intent of your routine seems to be that, given a sum total of `k` and a total number of terms `n`, to find all permutations of populating `n` terms with values that are between 0 and `k` inclusive.  I'm assuming that would mean that for the case `n=3, k=3`, you're looking for

```
3|0|0|
2|0|1|
2|1|0|
1|0|2|
1|1|1|
1|2|0|
0|0|3|
0|1|2|
0|2|1|
0|3|0|
```

Your code is a bit haphazard however.  In particular, the loop `for(int iter=0;iter<=k-firstindexval;iter++)` is completely unnecessary given the if statement inside it, and can be replaced by directly declaring the `k` in the recursive call to be `k - firstindexval`.  All code inside your routine related to the method variable `String[] result` also seems to be completely unnecessary.

The main problem with your code is that it returns void, and recursive calls do not pass the current state of recursion - in other words, you're not making using of a stack directly or indirectly, which makes it very difficult to remember the current state of your solution while you're traversing the recursive tree.

For example, in your question after `2|1|0|`, your next result is `0|1|` instead of the correct `2|0|1|` because the recursion did not know how to append the earlier state `2|` to the answers in your array, i.e. the "stack state" is not maintained in the generated answers.

One quick way to get your code to work is to add an additional String argument to `multichoose` which contains the state of the recursion, as below.  The comments I've added to your code explains the changes.

```
public static void multichoose(int n,int k, String currentSolution /* NEW ARGUMENT */)
{
    // String[] result = null; /* UNNECESSARY */
    System.out.print("Calling multichoose with");
    System.out.println("  "+Integer.toString(n)+"  "+Integer.toString(k));
    if(n==1)
    {
        // multinomial_elements[result_iter]=multinomial_elements[result_iter]+Integer.toString(k)+"|";
        multinomial_elements[result_iter]=currentSolution+k+"|"; /* CHANGED */
        ++result_iter;
    }
    else
    {
        if(k==0)
        {
            // result=new String[1]; /* UNNECESSARY */
            // result[0]="0"; /* UNNECESSARY */
            for(int a=0;a<n;a++)
                // multinomial_elements[result_iter]=multinomial_elements[result_iter]+"0"+"|";
                currentSolution += "0|"; /* CHANGED */
            multinomial_elements[result_iter] = currentSolution; /* NEW */
            ++result_iter;   
        }
        else 
        {
            for(int firstindexval=k;firstindexval>=0;firstindexval--)
                //for(int iter=0;iter<=k-firstindexval;iter++) /* UNNECESSARY */ 
                //{ /* UNNECESSARY */
                    //if(iter+firstindexval==k){ /* UNNECESSARY */

                        //multinomial_elements[result_iter]=multinomial_elements[result_iter]+Integer.toString(firstindexval)+"|"; /* SEE CHANGE BELOW */

                        //multichoose(n-1,iter);
                        multichoose(n-1, k-firstindexval /* CHANGED */, currentSolution+firstindexval+"|" /* NEW ARGUMENT */); /* CHANGED */
                    //} /* UNNECESSARY */

                //} /* UNNECESSARY */

        }
    }

}
```

There are probably better ways to do the recursion however.